# (React) Sliding/Sticky navbar hidden behind images?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

My sliding navbar gets sucked in at the top and when i scroll down it is behind the images.
I want it to be in front of the images like what this website does https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp (yes i tried following their code exactly but then i get TypeError: Navbar is null) (So i was trying to code a different version based off of theirs)

my code

```
Header.js

import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap'

import './Header.scss'

const alwaysOptions = (
  <Fragment>
    <Nav.Link href="#/" className="btn btn-light">Home</Nav.Link>
    <Nav.Link href="#/Anime-list" className="btn btn-warning">Anime List</Nav.Link>
    <Nav.Link href="https://notARealSite.com" target='_blank' rel="noopener noreferrer" className="btn btn-danger">Cartoons</Nav.Link>
  </Fragment>
)

const Header = ({ user }) => (
  <Navbar bg="dark" expand="md" id="navbar">
    <Navbar.Brand href="#">
      <h3 className="navbarTitle">Anime Stream</h3>
    </Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
    <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
      <Nav className="ml-auto">
        { alwaysOptions }
      </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Navbar>
)

window.onscroll = function () { scrollFunction() }

const scrollFunction = () => {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    document.getElementById('navbar').style.top = '0'
  } else {
    document.getElementById('navbar').style.top = '-50px'
  }
}

export default Header
```

```
Header.scss

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: -50px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}
```

output: https://prnt.sc/10vcl0j (the navbar is sucked in at the top of the page)
2nd output (after scrolling down): https://prnt.sc/10vcm7e (the navbar is behind the images)

Comment: I suspect that if you look at the CSS attached to those images, you'll find that they have a [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) assigned. Try setting your navbar's z-index higher than theirs.

Comment: @samuei that fixed the problem thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that if you look at the CSS attached to those images, you'll find that they have a z-index assigned. Try setting your navbar's z-index higher than theirs.

- samuei